# Need more about magento basic

Tags: magento

I'm new to magento. Need basic knowledge about magento programming, and magento customization.

Struggle to print content inside frontend.
I followed below site to  print content but error shows inside layout,where the content displayed.

Can help me what is what in magento

Comment: Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers and not a tutorial based portal. You can obviously take help of Google to know more about Magento.

Comment: You should look for a tutorial site. Magento Knowledge Base, Magento Community Tutorials are some better platform.

Comment: http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base

Comment: @DeepakMankotia Thankyou very much for your guideness. I gothrough this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easy learn i have searched it

1. It's a great and simple tutorial which help you step by step(After covering this tutorial you will be able to handle admin panel of the magento)

http://www.templatemonster.com/help/ecommerce/magento/magento-tutorials/
http://leveluptuts.com/tutorials/magento-community-tutorials

Comment: Mughak Thank you for your response. leveluptuts.com help me lot. Once again thanks for given guideness.